# Regex split with quotes and colon

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regexp-replace

I've seen a thousand posts about regex and matching quoted terms, etc. but none of them seem to give me what I need and despite my best efforts I'm honestly pretty terrible with regex, especially when you get into looking forward/backward and such, which is what I think I need here.

I have a single text box for users to enter a search.  It may be a single word, or it may have some hints for which field to search (colon for text fields, or a > or < for date/numeric fields).  In this example, I'm searching anything containing the word blue or dark blue, written by John Smith, with the word Foo in the title, and published after 1/1/2020.  Some of this is similar syntax to Google's search.

`blue "dark blue" author:"john smith" title:foo published>20200101`

There are a few factors to consider.  First, I have to keep `dark` and `blue` together, `john` and `smith` together as a single search term.  Then I have to split things out (the : < or >) and decide which field to search.

As a step one, I'd like to just get an array that looks like this:

```
blue
"dark blue"
author:"john smith"
title:foo 
published>20200101
```

Then step two would be to figure out if each term has an operator like author, title, etc.

If that can be rolled into one expression that would be great, but I'm certainly not counting on it.

Can anyone help me with this regex pattern?  Thanks so much!  For whatever it's worth I'm using C#/.NET for any kind of nuance.

Answer (score 0):

You may try doing a regex split on the following pattern:

```
[ ](?="|\w+:|\w+>)
```

### Demo

The regex used here says to split on a space `[ ]`, according to this logic:

```
[ ]       split on space, which is followed by
(?=
    "     a double quote
    |     OR
    \w+:  a word term followed by colon :
    | OR
    \w+>  a word term followed by >
)
```

Note that the `(?=...)` term is a lookaround, and asserts, but does *not* actually consume any text.  The only thing consumed during the split is the single space.

Comment: That's really great, thank you @Tim!  Can you explain how it works in English so I can feel educated rather than spoon-fed the answer?  Also, what about handling this scenario where the "generic" term blue is somewhere in the middle like so?

```"dark blue" author:"john smith" blue title:foo published>20200101```

Comment: @mateoc15 I have added an explanation on the regex.  I tried coming up with C# code, but I am not a C# person, so had some difficulty.

Comment: makes perfect sense, thanks for the explanation!  How about the second case in my comment where "blue" is inserted somewhere in the middle of those terms rather than the beginning?
```"dark blue" author:"john smith" BLUE title:foo published>20200101```

Comment: It gets hairy very quickly.  There is another even worse edge case `"john michael smith"`.  Really, you need a parser here in the general case.

Comment: As long as "john michael smith" is all in quotes it seems to work fine for me.  I realize it gets hairy.  Even if I don't get a single regex I'm still not quite sure how to identify BLUE in the middle of the string.

This is infinitely further than I've gotten so far, so thank you so much.